# Why sometimes Eclispe will break even when I do not set the breakpoint?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I debug some code, eclipse will break at some points which I do not set break points. I can continue to debug, but I would like to know what maybe the cause of this behavior?

Comment: There are also breakpoints on exceptions that can be set. Are there no breakpoints listed in the Breakpoints view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there is a compile error in the program, and that line is executed Eclipse will halt there.

Also check the Breakpoints view if there are any breakpoints there. There are several kinds of breakpoints besides the usual 'Line breakpoint' e.g. exception breakpoint, class load breakpoint etc.